# Конфигурирование параметров TLS в Requests(edha curve)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, requests

Требуется создать подключение с помощью https протокола, при этом на сервере размещен сертификат, сгенерированный на основе эллиптической кривой brainpoolP256r1. 
Когда я посылаю запрос с помощью Request, в пакете TLS Client Hello по умолчанию нет поддержки данной кривой, поэтому сервер отвечает отказом(handshake failure), требуется выставить этот параметр при формировании запроса. К сожалению, я не смог найти возможность это сделать. Нашел статьи, вроде этой
https://lukasa.co.uk/2017/02/Configuring_TLS_With_Requests/
но в них описана возможность указать версию протокола TLS и список cipher suites, но нет про ecdh curve.
В итоге сделал с помощью библиотеки ssl:

```py
context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.set_ecdh_curve("brainpoolP256r1")
con = http.client.HTTPSConnection("blabla.com", 443, context=context)
```

но она работает с библиотекой http.client, а хотелось бы использовать Requests.
Спасибо!